# ObsoleteLintCustomCheck lint warning after upgrade to WorkManager 2.3.4

Tags: android, lint, android-workmanager

After upgrading WorkManager from 2.2.0 to 2.3.4, I get a new `ObsoleteLintCustomCheck` lint warning. If I understand the warning message right, then they added a new lint check that uses an old API version? Google doesn't show anything useful related to `WorkManagerIssueRegistry` though.

Anyone ran into this issue before or has an idea how to fix this?

In gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.4"
testImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:2.3.4"
```

```
Lint found an issue registry (`androidx.work.lint.WorkManagerIssueRegistry`) which is older than 
the current API level; these checks may not work correctly. Recompile the checks against the 
latest version. Custom check API version is 3 (3.3), current lint API level is 6 (3.6+)

Lint can be extended with "custom checks": additional checks implemented by 
developers and libraries to for example enforce specific API usages required by a library or a 
company coding style guideline. The Lint APIs are not yet stable, so these checks may either 
cause a performance degradation, or stop working, or provide wrong results. This warning flags 
custom lint checks that are found to be using obsolete APIs and will need to be updated to run 
in the current lint environment. It may also flag issues found to be using a **newer** version 
of the API, meaning that you need to use a newer version of lint (or Android Studio or Gradle 
plugin etc) to work with these checks.
```

Comment: For now i've suppressed this error in `lint.xml`, but i would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore this. We fixed this in `WorkManager 2.4.x`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll remove the ignore once we upgrade to 2.4

Comment: Wow! someone just fixed that like a charm-engineer from Goog-warts! nice! Thanks!